# Menu button opening keyboard

Tags: android, android-service, android-softkeyboard, keylistener

I would like to know how the keyboard pops up on long press of the hardware menu button. I've read that key listeners aren't available in services. So, how exactly does the menu button trigger the keyboard to show up?

**EDIT**

Since my question seems a bit incoherent, here's what I mean.

When I'm in the app drawer and press the menu button for long, the keyboard pops up. Or if I'm using an app and long press the menu button again, the keyboard still pops up.

So, I'm assuming that it's the keyboard service, but services don't have key listeners.

How is this possible then?

Comment: I think you must declare your focus on your layout. I assumed there is an edittext with onfocus on create

Comment: @Androyds You aren't understanding my question. This is nothing to do with app development. 

While using your device, when you long press the hardware menu button(no matter which app is in your foreground), the keyboard pops up. How does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NO way to add a keyListener to a Service in Android. The menu button triggers the keyboard in mine because it's a custom mod and the function was embedded in the framework itself. Not because of a service keylistener or other theories.

If you're curious, I'm using CM7.2.0-buzz

Answer (score 0):

put this code on your button listener

If you want to show screen keyboard

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

if you want to hide it

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keycode, KeyEvent event){         
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){    
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(lv, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);             
    }
    return true;
}
```